# Unable to Update Table from Stored Procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table in a database, previously existing, no knowledge of any changes to said table, that is unable to be updated by a stored procedure as of late.  The error received is "Error Code: 1615. Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared."  The stored procedure, which I have slimmed down to try to deduce the issue is:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS db1.sp_change_dates;//

CREATE DEFINER=`serviceAdmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `db1.sp_change_dates`()
begin 
    SET @stmt_text = 'update db1.activity set createStamp = (createStamp + interval 1 day);';
    PREPARE update_stmt FROM @stmt_text;
    EXECUTE update_stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE update_stmt;
END

//
DELIMITER ;
```

The table definition is as follows:

```
   CREATE TABLE `activity` (
  `id` decimal(30,0) NOT NULL,
  `v` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createStamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `modifiedStamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdBy` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modifiedBy` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEPRECATED_ownerOrg` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `testData` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `activityCategoryOid` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `activitySubCategoryOid` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rootActivityOid` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(8096) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEPRECATED_referencedItemobjectIdStr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEPRECATED_referencedItemClazzName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEPRECATED_referencedItemName` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentActivityOid` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fillInDate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `fillInDateHour` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fillInLocalDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `fillInLocalDateHour` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `providerId` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `beginDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `beginDateHour` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `beginLocalDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `beginLocalDateHour` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `activityClassEnum` enum('Case','Task','Memo','Opportunity') DEFAULT NULL,
  `assignedToOid` decimal(30,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_subject` (`subject`),
  KEY `idx_fillInDate` (`fillInDate`),
  KEY `idx_organization` (`organization`),
  KEY `idx_parentActivityOid` (`parentActivityOid`),
  KEY `idx_createdBy` (`createdBy`),
  KEY `idx_createStamp` (`createStamp`),
  KEY `idx_active` (`active`),
  KEY `idx_activityCategoryOid` (`activityCategoryOid`),
  KEY `idx_modifiedStamp` (`modifiedStamp`),
  KEY `idx_contact` (`contact`),
  KEY `idx_rootActivityOid` (`rootActivityOid`),
  KEY `idx_priorityWeight` (`priority_id`),
  KEY `idx_referencedItemobjectIdStr` (`DEPRECATED_referencedItemobjectIdStr`),
  KEY `idx_beginDate` (`beginDate`),
  KEY `idx_idx_beginDateHour` (`beginDateHour`),
  KEY `idx_idx_beginLocalDate` (`beginLocalDate`),
  KEY `idx_idx_beginLocalDateHour` (`beginLocalDateHour`),
  KEY `idx_idx_fillInDateHour` (`fillInDateHour`),
  KEY `idx_idx_fillInLocalDate` (`fillInLocalDate`),
  KEY `idx_idx_fillInLocalDateHour` (`fillInLocalDateHour`),
  KEY `idx_activitySubCategoryOid` (`activitySubCategoryOid`),
  KEY `idx_activityClassEnum` (`activityClassEnum`),
  KEY `IDX_id` (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_assignedTo_organization` (`assignedToOid`,`organization`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I tried this in another database (we have the same database for multiple clients) and was able to run the stored procedure without issue.  The database with issue is running MySQL 5.6.34.  I've seen a few bugs that seem similar to this issue, but none were without the introduction of another software or language (e.g. PHP).  I am at a loss as to what to search for and will gladly provide more system information if that will help.  I did not architect the database originally and am trying to pick up where another left off.  Thanks in advance.  My user's permissions are `ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* WITH GRANT OPTION.`

Comment: are there triggers on this table? have they all been identified? disabled? double-check even if you think you got them all

Comment: I am in a bit of a pinch there.  There are triggers on the tables that the process is failing on but I cannot disable them as they are integral to our software.  Also, this process used to run fine with the triggers enabled at that time too.  I am a bit new to all of this--can stored procedures not update tables with triggers on them normally?

Comment: If it helps at all, when the activity table is updated (which the prepared statement does) the trigger pulls the data from this table and populates a view.  I had read there are issues with the "Prepared statement needs to be reprepared" when the update is made on a view, but perhaps because there is a trigger resulting in action to the view I am seeing some similar issue?

Also of note, after a restart of mysql the procedure is able to be run one time before the resulting error occurs again on the second attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by increasing the table_definition_cache from 2000 to 7900.